# Will I feel a shock using this circuit?

Tags: arduino, step-up, shock

I'm a programmer and new to electronics.

I am trying to achieve at least slightly shocking my finger using this circuit and want to make sure it works before buying the stuff. It will be a punishment for my c++ productivity application.

Can anybody tell me if this will work?

[image]

This is the boost.
https://dratek.cz/arduino/51529-boost-buck-step-up-modul-solarniho-napajeni-nastavitelny-dc-dc-xl6009.html

Comment: Probably not, but intentionally shocking yourself is not safe or recommended.  There are devices out there that are specifically designed to do it (toys and the like) but even then it's not 100% safe.

Comment: Consider emitting an annoying audio clip; can do that totally from software.

Comment: @rdtsc Excellent idea.  It could play "Never Gonna Give You Up" or anything by ABBA.

Comment: Unfortunately I already have it as punishment and I kinda need more of them.. do you think it would work with this boost step up? 

https://techfun.sk/cs/produkt/vysokonapatovy-dc-dc-boost-konverter-3-6v-na-8200v/?lang=cs&currency=CZK&gclid=Cj0KCQjwguGYBhDRARIsAHgRm49Rww--DLMMLp3dRGBEsyArPfswm3gZyIHJj0uJ-BU6s9dRHVjXSNoaAnXfEALw_wcB

punishments:
delete random file,
loud speaker,
jumpscare,
textove upominky,
rick anstley,
prodlouzeni casu,
URAZKA,
shock,
rewards:
pochvala

Comment: You'll condition yourself to be unproductive without that thing... And that also means that you'll be productive in C++ but not much else. It's not even a great idea on paper, never mind in practice. Forget about it. You're not a dog. You can think yourself into being productive, rather than shock yourself into it.

Comment: The only moment when punisment will be used in my app is when you launch a videogame or something you procrastinate in. It's a windows app. I have the idea sorted I just need help with this. It's a fun school project.

Comment: imagine dying because of adhd

Comment: I need something like that to keep me off stack exchange!

Answer (score 0):

This application is dangerous, because those devices can output higher current than would be safe assuming human-skin resistance allows it.

In addition, your transistor is NPN, and will function better as a switch positioned between the negative terminal of the DC converter and the battery.

However, from a safety standpoint, I am seconding the comments to use a non-electrical method of startling yourself.  Perhaps consider a 15khz tone generator -- very annoying and ultimately harmless.

Comment: 15kHz doesn't bother me at all (anymore).

Answer (score 0):

you're looking to build a shock encouragement machine.  best results is usually had by using a very high voltage constrained to be at a low current because this cancels out the extreme variablity of skin resistance.

I'd start with a cheap high voltage generator like https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4001151131137.html
but it will probably need to be modified to reduce the output power.